# Meteor build packages not included

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, meteor

I am currently trying to generate native versions of a small meteor app I built. When I run them on iOS or Android via the `meteor run` command it works and `meteor build` with `--debug` also generates an ipa/apk that works as expected. But when I run `meteor build` without `--debug` the web view only shows a white screen. Using remote debugging I noticed an injector error. I was wondering why and checked the apk/ipa content. There I recognized that in the debug version under `assets/www/application/packages` there is a bunch of .js and .js.map files which simply is not there in the non-debug ipa/apk.

In the index.html of the non-debug ipa/apk the imports of these files are also missing.

How can I tell meteor to just copy these obviously required files for non-debug?

Answer (score 0):

When you build, Meteor concatenates and minifies all the JS files into a single bundle, same as Browserify and webpack are doing. That is why you do not see all the script imports.

It does not do it in debug to facilitate live reload / hot code push while you are developing, besides facilitating debugging​ obviously.

See the Meteor guide on building for production.

If you believe this difference causes some issue, you can simulate it in development using the `--production` flag after `meteor run`.

This addresses your titled and last question, but may not fix in itself your initial issue.